# Mapping json with RestKit 0.20.3

Tags: ios, json, parsing, mapping, restkit-0.20

I'm trying to map objects through RestKit 0.20.3, but I'm having those logs for days know:

```
2013-08-12 18:32:08.158 MyAppIphone[848:5703] E restkit.network:RKResponseMapperOperation.m:304 Failed to parse response data: Loaded an unprocessable response (200) with content type 'application/json'

2013-08-12 18:32:08.174 MyAppIphone[848:5703] E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:238 POST 'myUrl' (200 OK / 0 objects) 

[request=0.1305s mapping=0.0000s total=5.6390s]:
error=Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=-1017 "Loaded an unprocessable response (200) with content type 'application/json'" 

UserInfo=0x1ed5a500 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=myUrl, NSUnderlyingError=0x1ed5b240 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)", NSLocalizedDescription=Loaded an unprocessable response (200) with content type 'application/json'}

response.body={"my json content"}
```

Here is MyData class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyData : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *criterias;

@end
```

Here is how I set up my mapper:

```
- (RKResponseDescriptor*) getDataMapping
{
    // Mapping
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MyData class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"criteriasHeader":        @"criteriasHeader"
     }];

    // Status code
    NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);

    // Descriptior
    return [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping method:RKRequestMethodPOST pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"regions" statusCodes:statusCodes];
}
```

Here my requesting function:

```
- (void) runRequestWithType:(RequestType)type baseUrl:(NSString *)baseUrlString path:(NSString *)path parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters mapping:(RKResponseDescriptor *) descriptor
{
    // Print heeader and body from the request and the response
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);
    RKLogConfigureByName("Restkit/Network", RKLogLevelDebug);
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelTrace);
    RKLogConfigureByName("Restkit/ObjectMapping", RKLogLevelDebug);

    // Set up the base url
    NSURL *baseUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:baseUrlString];

    //Run request in block
    RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:baseUrl];
    [manager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[descriptor]];

    [manager.router.routeSet addRoute:[RKRoute routeWithClass:[MyData class] pathPattern:path method:RKRequestMethodPOST]];
    //[manager getObjectsAtPath:path parameters:parameters success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    [manager postObject:nil path:path parameters:parameters success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidSucceedWithType:andResponse:)]) {
            [self.delegate requestDidSucceedWithType:type andResponse:[mappingResult firstObject]];
        }
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(requestDidFailWithError:andError:)]) {
            [self.delegate requestDidFailWithType:type andError:error];
        }
    }];
}
```

PS: I tried with a shorter JSON, it works well.

Did I do something wrong?

Could you help me, thanks.

Comment: `postObject` means that you are trying to send some object to your server, but you are passing a nil object. Is this really what you want? Is really a POST and not a GET method that you are looking for?

Comment: Also, show the JSON and check the names of the keys used in your mapping.

Comment: Lucas: You're right I need GET method.
Wain: I re-checked JSON, it's totally valid.
Thanks guys.

Actually it when I get a value with accent in my JSON I guess it's because my API/DB is encoded in ISO/IEC 8859-15 (latin 9), the problem is that I can't unfortunately change it to UTF-8.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The underlyingError form the - (id)parseResponseData:(NSError **)error function in RKResponseMapperOperation.m is equal to:
underlyingError= Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unable to convert data to string around character 963.) UserInfo=0x8258cc0 {NSDebugDescription=Unable to convert data to string around character 963.}

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error comes from JSON mapping under RK. Default is to use NSJSONSerialization encapsulated in RKNSJSONSerialization. You can put a breakpoint there to find out maybe more about the error.
I found 2 sources until now:

- NSJSONSerialization doesn't like non UTF8 data. Make sure you either receive it from server, or modify RK to do the proper conversion from data to string(with correct encoding) to UTF8-data(best way i have so far). If using CoreData you can look in RKManagedObjectRequestOperation at line 586.
- in iOS5 there are bugs. Easiest fix is to use another parsing library

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you are able to change the server encoding of the JSON to UTF-8.

If not, you can resolve this issue by replacing the default JSON mime type handler in Restkit. Use the Restkit class `RKNSJSONSerialization` as reference.

In your custom JSON mime type handler, perform data conversion from the incoming encoding (in the example below ISO-8859-1) to UTF-8, before doing the same as the `RKNSJSONSerialization` class.

```
@implementation MyCustomJSONSerializer    

+ (id)objectFromData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)error
{
    NSString* latin = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[data bytes] length:[data length] encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];

    NSData* utf8 = [latin dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:utf8 options:0 error:error];
}

@end
```

You can do similar for the `dataFromObject` method if you must POST data back to the server in non-UTF-8 encoding.

You can now add this custom handler **after** you init Restkit, and it will be used vs the default (UTF-8) one:

```
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[MyCustomJSONSerializer class] forMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
```